# Using cookies in Perl without CGI

Tags: perl, cookies, cgi

I am trying to create a standard forum style website using Perl but not using CGI, or any other framework for that matter. I've seen before use of a script simply titled "cookies.pl," but can't find any sort of documentation on it. Is there a way to set/read cookies with just core modules?

Comment: What reason do you have for wanting to use a 25-year-old non-core module `cookies.pl` but not something newer? (I'm guessing at the age, but the fact that it's a .pl file means it probably predates Perl5, which was first released in 1994.)

Comment: By "not using CGI", do you mean not using the `CGI` Perl module, or not using the CGI interface at all? If the latter, what are you using instead?

Comment: @ikegami I was asking only because it was the only resource I knew of that didn't involve a large framework (or CGI.pm)

Comment: I was okay with it, because it was all I knew of. I dislike CGI.pm in part because it's no longer in the core, but more so due to spite because anytime I need documentation, that's all I can find.

Comment: There are more options out there than `CGI.pm` and "large frameworks". I personally use Dancer and Mojolicious is also quite popular these days; both of them are commonly described as "microframeworks" and I believe that they are smaller than `CGI.pm`. (I know the main module for Dancer is about a quarter the size of `CGI.pm`, but haven't tried to add in the size of any other core-Dancer modules.) Or you could try `CGI::Lite`, which is smaller still.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I am assuming that when you say you don't want to use "CGI", you mean the Perl module `CGI.pm` rather than the Common Gateway Interface (CGI) method of communicating with the web server, which is implemented by the `CGI.pm` module.

Second, this answer is for information and entertainment purposes only.  Attempting to implement your own CGI handler for use in a production environment is not advisable.  It's a Really, Really Bad Idea unless you know exactly what you're doing.  And probably still a Bad Idea even if you do.  And if you did know exactly what you're doing, you wouldn't have to ask questions about basic parts of the interface like how to implement cookie handling.

With all that out of the way, cookies are pretty simple to handle directly.

- To set a cookie, send a `Set-Cookie` HTTP header to the client. In the most basic form, this looks like `Set-Cookie: CookieName=CookieValue`. There are many other options which can be added to this basic format, which are [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) in various places around the web.

If you're now wondering "How do I send an HTTP header?", every line of text that you send to the client (i.e., `print` to `STDOUT`) prior to the first empty line is an HTTP header:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n";            # Content-Type header is mandatory!
print "Set-Cookie: CookieName=CookieValue\n"; # Header to set a cookie
print "\n";                                   # Blank line = end of headers
# continue on with sending the response body now that headers are done
```

- To read a cookie, look at the environment variable `HTTP_COOKIE`, which is provided by the web server as a part of its CGI implementation and will contain a semicolon-delimited list of all cookies received with the client's HTTP request.  This is accessed in Perl as `$ENV{HTTP_COOKIE}`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I did mean CGI.pm. I understand my methods are not standard, and will need to update myself in the future, but I think this will suit my purposes until then.

Comment: @GeoffH. - The issue isn't so much that it's non-standard or will need updates in the future. The problem is that you're likely to introduce security bugs (`CGI.pm` has certainly had its share of security issues over the years) and, if you're using a custom CGI handler that nobody else uses, then those flaws won't be found until your site is exploited - and may not be found even then.